# simpLESS not compiling

Tags: css, less

I am using 'simpLESS' program to compile my .less files into .css files on the fly.

It is really great!

However, after using it only for couple of days, 'simpLESS' stopped copiling the .less into .css files.
I have tried to reinstall, redownload and then reinstall, tried other directories, other .less files, tried recompiling manuall - but nothing works.

Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did anything change on your machine between when it was working and when it stopped? Perhaps you moved directories? Changed accounts? Switched from running the program directly to a shortcut? A batch file?

Comment: Thank you all guys for your help, but I found the problem. :)

Comment: If you think others could have the same problem it would be great if you could write an answer that might help others fix it! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to found the problem.
I had the following code:

```
#result{
   .result_padding;

   .icon{
      height: 17px;
      width: 23px;
    }
}
```

However, the ".result_padding" actually was not defined. The simpLESS compiler should have spotted this, but I guess this is a bug. Anyway, after removing this line - it worked.

Comment: It seems this problem is still current in 1.4, thanks for pointing out what was causing your problem.  Time to hunt out the undefines...

Answer (score 5):

Simpless is always bad with error handling! instead of telling you what's wrong it just doesn't work! So here is what I do: when Simpless doesn't display the error I use [Winless](http://winless.org/) to find the error and after I fix it I go back to Simpless.
note: I use Simpless because it works fine with @import .less files in the other hand Winless doesn't.